# Transform different to its own inverse

Tags: ros, navigation, tf2, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When configuring `robot_localization` today I came across a weird phenomenon which is, I think, an error. I'm using `navsat_transform_node` to take in our GPS data, and I have the `broadcast_utm_transform` parameter set to `true`. When using `tf_monitor` to view the transforms `utm -> map` and `map -> utm`, they actually differ in translational value, and one is not the negative of the other. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/5QswT) for the result of `tf_monitor`. The time says '0.000', meaning it is a static transform, so it doesn't seem like it can be multiple publishers.

**robot_localization.launch**

```
  <node name="NavSatTransform" pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0.1917"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
    <param name="broadcast_utm_transform" value="true"/>
    <param name="broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame" value="true"/>
    <param name="delay" value="5"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>
    <param name="publish_filtered_gps" value="false"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude" value="true"/>
    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="phidgets_gps/data"/>
    <remap from="/imu/data" to="phidgets_imu/data_filtered"/>
    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="robot_localization_all/odom"/>
    <remap from="/odometry/gps" to="phidgets_gps/data_filtered"/>
    <rosparam param="datum">[-27.454919, 153.029867, 0.0]</rosparam>
  </node>

  <node name="RobotLocalizationCts" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency" value="10"/>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="3"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_acceleration" value="false"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
    <remap from="set_pose" to="robot_localization_cts/set_pose"/>
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="robot_localization_cts/odom"/>
    <param name="odom0" value="tracks_diff_drive_with_position_controller/odom"/>
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    true,  true,  true,
                                    false, false, true,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
    <param name="imu0" value="phidgets_imu/data_filtered"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true,]</rosparam>
        <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>
        <param name="imu0_relative" value="false"/>
        <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>
        <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>
  </node>

  <node name="RobotLocalizationAll" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency" value="10"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="3"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_acceleration" value="false"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="map"/>
    <remap from="set_pose" to="robot_localization_all/set_pose"/>
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="robot_localization_all/odom"/>
    <param name="odom0" value="tracks_diff_drive_with_position_controller/odom"/>
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    true,  true,  true,
                                    false, false, true,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
    <param name="odom1" value="phidgets_gps/data_filtered"/>
    <rosparam param="odom1_config">[true,  true,  false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom1_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom1_queue_size" value="10"/>
    <param name="imu0" value="phidgets_imu/data_filtered"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true,]</rosparam>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>
  </node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261733/transform-different-to-its-own-inverse/) by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 885 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be correct. The translation is not the same because there is a slight rotation in this transform. In that case, the translation does not need to be negative of the inverse transform. For a visual explanation, consider the following picture:

[image description http://www.gamasutra.com/features/20020510/image001.gif](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/20020510/image001.gif)

When expressing the location of `frame_1` in the coordinates of `frame_0` and vice versa, you can see that the norm will be the same, but the direction of the vector won't be. (In this case, the T vector of `frame_0` expressed in `frame_1` will be almost aligned with the `-X1` axis, as opposed to the direction of the negative of the drawn T vector.)

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-15**:
Yes yes of course. I guess I hadn't come across a transform with a rotation before, and it is late in the day here so my brain couldn't fathom it. Thanks for that!